# iPhone PDF creation text inverting issue

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-2d

i am creating an iphone app for creating pdf. I am using the following code:

```
    [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20 )text:@"last Name"xVal:10 yVal:-30 len:9];
    [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20 )text:@"First Name"xVal:180 yVal:30 len:10];
    [self drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20 )text:@"Middle Name"xVal:330 yVal:-30 len:11];

    + (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect text:(NSString *)string xVal:(int)x yVal:(int)y len:(int)length{
        CGContextRef theContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
        CGRect viewBounds = rect;
        CGContextTranslateCTM(theContext, 0, viewBounds.size.height); 
        CGContextScaleCTM(theContext, 1, -1);
        // Draw the text using the MyDrawText function 
        MyDrawText(theContext, viewBounds,string, x, y,length);
    }
void MyDrawText (CGContextRef myContext, CGRect contextRect, NSString *textToDraw, int x, int y, int len){
    float w, h; 
    w = contextRect.size.width; 
    h = contextRect.size.height;
    CGAffineTransform myTextTransform;

    CGContextSelectFont (myContext,"Helvetica-Bold", h, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

    CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (myContext, 3);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (myContext, kCGTextFill);   
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);    

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (myContext, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    myTextTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0); 
    CGContextSetTextMatrix (myContext, myTextTransform); 
    const char *str = [textToDraw UTF8String];
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint (myContext, x, y,str, len);
}
```

When I use this code I am getting the output like, first and third word is fine but the second one is coming like inverted (head down). Why so? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with `CGContextRef theContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`, when each time the function calls, the `CGContext` taking the last state, that's why getting the inverting output. So, i added,

```
CGContextRef theContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSaveGState(theContext);
//code to draw....
CGContextRestoreGState(theContext);
```

this solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`Core Graphics` considers **Bottom-Left** corner as the origin for drawing.(In `UIKit` its **Top-Left**).

Here in your method call for second string you are providing `yVal` as 30 and other values as -30.

Thanks,

Comment: yVal just changing the position in Y axis. That is not controlling the inverting nature of the text. I changed that to 30, still no change but the position has been changed.